# Sending chunked response in Flask-restful that depends on async requests

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous, python-asyncio, flask-restful

I have a flask-restful server where I need to send data chunk by chunk to the front-end to show the progress that's being made in the server. That progress depends on requests being successful and those requests are async. I wish I could have a response object similar to expressjs or I could use the async generator directly but I have found no way to do that, so I've tried to make the asynchronous generator synchronous.

In the function do, the requests are being made and added to request tracker (the method add in Request_Tracker), then after the response is successful, the response is added to the responses in Request_Tracker and the Wait_For_Update function is updated. Wait_For_Update has an internal task and the update method just cancels the task and makes a new one. The problem is, generate_sync waits for the requests to be made and just then tries to get the next request from Request_Tracker. I assume that's the case because the loop is busy with the requests and run_until_complete waits for everything in the loop to be done before starting. How do I fix that?

I have the following architecture:

route.py

```
class Class_Name(Resource):
    async def post_async(self, loop):
        requests_data = {
            "total": float,
            "request_tracker": Request_Tracker(loop)
        }
        
        async def do():
            #...do things that make async requests, some of them happening simultaneously
            await requests_data["request_tracker"].finish()
        
        async def generate():
            while not requests_data["request_tracker"].get_is_finished():
                yield await requests_data["request_tracker"].await_next()
        
        loop.create_task(do())
        
        def generate_sync():
            gen = generate()
            while True:
                try:
                    yield loop.run_until_complete(gen.__anext__())
                except StopAsyncIteration as e:
                    break
        
        return generate_sync()
    def post(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        response_generator = loop.run_until_complete(self.post_async(loop))
        return app.response_class(stream_with_context(response_generator), mimetype="txt")

api.add_resource(Class_Name, '/endpoint')
```

request_tracker.py

```
async def wait_forever():
    await asyncio.sleep(1000000)

class Wait_For_Update:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop
        self._new()
        self.is_updating = False
    def _new(self):
        self.task = self.loop.create_task(wait_forever())
    async def cancel(self):
        self.task.cancel()
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
    async def update(self):
        #this checking for is_updating is done so a task isn't being cancelled multiple times
        if self.is_updating:
            return
        self.is_updating = True
        await self.cancel()
        self._new()
        self.is_updating = False

class Request_Tracker:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.is_finished = False
        self.responses = Responses()
        self.wait_for_update = Wait_For_Update(loop)
        self.loop = loop
    
    async def add(self, req):
        res = await req
        self.responses.add(res)
        await self.wait_for_update.update()
        return res
    
    async def finish(self):
        await self.wait_for_update.cancel()
        self.is_finished = True
    
    def get_is_finished(self):
        return self.is_finished and len(self.responses) == 0
    
    async def await_next(self):
        while True:
            if self.responses.has_responses():
                return self.responses
            if self.get_is_finished():
                return
            await self.wait_for_update.task
```